# Uso de <td> y <tr>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Que puedo hacer para que el nombre del empleado me quede horizontal y no vertical como se muestra en la imagen 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta como utilizo en td

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que darle estilos a ese td para que ocupe todo el texto.

Comment: como le doy estilo a td jdev podrias ayudarme

Comment: Aumentando el width de la columna se soluciona colega

Comment: Tengo                         <td>@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</td>  como lo aumento  bro

Comment: Yo lo metería dentro de un <p style="white-space: nowrap;"></p>

Comment: Como quedaria con este                          <td>@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</td>

Comment: <td><p style="white-space: nowrap;">@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</p></td>

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera aumentar el width no sirve. No sabes el valor necesario porque depende de los datos.

Comment: @JDev  porque no me haces la respuesta para aceptarla , porque ya me funciono con eso, muchas gracias

Comment: @MarcoEufragio hecho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce el contenido del `<td>`en un `<p style="white-space: nowrap;"></p>`

En tu caso quedaría así

```
<td>
    <p style="white-space: nowrap;">@item.EmpNombre @item.EmpApellido</p>
</td>
```

La propiedad `white-space`establece como se van a tratar los espacios dentro de la etiqueta. En este caso le indicamos `nowrap` para que no inserte saltos de línea en el testo al ajustar. Para mas información de como funciona white-space visitar el siguiente [enlace](https://librosweb.es/libro/css_avanzado/capitulo_4/propiedad_white_space.html)

Comment: Hola @JDev. Partiendo de que tu respuesta es la correcta, podrías explicar porqué funciona? ¿Qué hace la propiedad white-space: nowrap? ¿Porque un p y no un label?

Comment: Editado @PabloSimonDiEstefano